# Owl Carousel partial view of next slide without looping

Tags: owl-carousel

Is it possible for owl carousel 1 to show partial view of the right slide once the number of slides exceed the specified number in the js, without using loop or stage-padding? Also, to display the end slide completely?

[• Here's a mock-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJQeW.png)